# Awesome WM: some clients pop up floating and vertically and horizontally maximized

Tags: awesome-wm

Some graphic clients such as firefox, thunderbird and sqlitebrowser pop up vertically and horizontally maximized automatically, and floating, without any specific rule in the rc.lua. Or at least I suppose they are so from the icons in the title bar, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyuI8.png). While others like thunar or blender work just fine.

This is annoying because I didn't find any way to remove this condition. I can make them non floating with mod + ctrl + space, but they are still maximized. Also, clients with such condition resize poorly, they are slightly wider than my main screen and step over to the next screen by a few pixels. I have to maximize them to make them fit the screen.

I did some research and couldn't find any answer to this problem.

Can this come from an obscure rule in the rc.lua? I didn't do much modification from the original example, and I believe this problem wasn't there before a recent awesome update.

I'm using awesome 4.1 on archlinux, with compton as compositing manager.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have a clear answer why it must be forced, but the solution of this [forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=226052) that proposes to modify the default rule for clients by adding the four last lines works for me:

```
{ rule = { },
  properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                 border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                 focus = awful.client.focus.filter,
                 raise = true,
                 keys = clientkeys,
                 buttons = clientbuttons,
                 screen = awful.screen.preferred,
                 placement = awful.placement.no_overlap+awful.placement.no_offscreen,
                 maximized_vertical   = false,
                 maximized_horizontal = false,
                 floating = false,
                 maximized = false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and I have a work-around which seems to work for me.  The vertical and horizontal maximization for a application-window goes away if I follow following steps after stating the application:

1. Make the application window non-floating (using `MOD + Ctrl + Space`)
2. Make the application-window full-screen (using `MOD + f` for me)
3. Restore the application-windows back ( `MOD + f` again to restore)

This removes vertical and horizontal maximization with which application had started for me (I am using `awesome v3.5.6` on Ubuntu `16.04 LTS`).

This work-around does not solve the general problem of starting the application window properly, but can be used to restore the older (and my preferred) behaviour to the application window.

Answer (score 0):

`Awesome 4.3` here on `Arch`, and I was mystified too by this affecting `nomacs` and `Thunderbird`, with them being stuck in floating mode. Then I found in [90-FAQ.md](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/docs/90-FAQ.md):

> ##### Why some floating clients can not be tiled?
>
> If some of your applications (i.e. Firefox, Opera...) are floating but you can't tile them, and they behave weird (can not be tagged, are always on top...) do not panic. They are merely maximized from your last window manager, or from their last invocation. The default key binding to toggle maximized state is "Mod4 + m".
> You can ensure no application ever starts maximized in the first rule of your `ruled.client.rules` table, which applies to all clients, by adding:

```lua
    -- Search for this rule,
    keys = clientkeys,

    -- add the following two:
    maximized_vertical   = false,
    maximized_horizontal = false,
```